# C: Warning when casting int to int* on Windows 64-bit machine when working on 32-bit program

Tags: c, windows, pointers, x86, clang

I'm working on a legacy 32-bit program where there are a lot of casts like `DWORD* a = (DWORD*)b`, where `b` is a native `int`, and I get lots of these warnings:

`Cast to 'DWORD *' (aka 'unsigned int*') from smaller integer type 'int' ['clang: -Wint-to-pointer-cast]`

Since the sizes are equal during compilation it's fine, but I don't see how Clang would know that. What can I do to satisfy this warning other than disabling it entirely?

EDIT: The premise of the question is bad due to my misunderstanding of Clang, a compiler, and clangd, the language server which invokes Clang. The language server didn't know I was targeting x86.

Comment: The warning is telling you that the sizes are *not* equal.  And they indeed would not be if you are compiling for a Win64 target.  Clang knows that because it has to in order to generate correct executable code for the target.  Possibly you want to tell Clang to build for Win32 instead, if it has a flag for that.

Comment: For a 32-bit target both pointers and `int`s are indeed the same size. This doesn't immediately result in an error, though Clang seems to unconditionally warn about int to pointer casts. You can change `b`s type to `int_ptr` to prevent the warning.

Comment: To put it another way: the sense of 32-bit *vs* 64-bit relevant to the warning is not a function of your source code, but rather of your compiler, build environment, and command-line options.  The code in question apparently makes a lot of unsafe assumptions related to sizes of datatypes, which happen to be correct for Win32.  If you just want to run the program, rather than taking up ongoing maintenance of it, then building it as a Win32 program is probably your easiest and safest option.

Comment: Thank you. In retrospect the entire question should just ask how to tell Clang I am targeting Win32.

Comment: How could Clang not know whether the sizes are equal or not? It knows the sizes of pointers and the size of `int` for the target it is compiling for. If it says `int` is smaller than `DWORD *`, then `int` is smaller than `DWORD *`. Maybe you are not compiling for the target you think you are.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm compiling using a separate compiler & use Clang strictly for the linting.

Comment: What does that mean? You are getting this message from Clang. Are you using Clang to generate error messages and using a separate compiler to generate object modules?

Comment: Yes. I compiled everything with MinGW32 but the error messages were generated using Clang, which did not target x86.

Comment: Mingw32 packages a version of GCC, and GCC is pretty good at code diagnosis, especially if you turn up the warning level ("`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`" may produce even more warnings than you really want).  It seems foolish to rely on a different compiler for linting than for compilation, as then you cannot expect to turn up implementation-specific issues, and you may run into problems with differing sets of extensions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It's indeed foolish. In my mind they were completely segregated & they worked pretty well, until now that is.

Comment: For anyone who is interested in answering, the main problem here is my confusion between Clang and clangd. With setting the language server to know I am targeting a x86 machine, clangd (not Clang) no longer gives me the warning. I mistakenly marked this as a Clang issue, but I've only been using clangd which invokes Clang during code analysis which had no way of knowing what is my target architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem is `(DWORD*)b` but `b` is of type `int`. This means the code needs to be redesigned, because somebody is stuffing pointers into `int`. Microsoft made a special type for a pointer-sized integer: `DWORD_PTR`. Yeah sure there's one in `stdint.h` and you can use that one if you want, but if you're already using `DWORD` you might as well use `DWORD_PTR`. The problem didn't happen on this line. The problem happened on the line where `b` was assigned the value from a pointer.

Change type of `b` to `intptr_t`, `uintptr_t`, or `DWORD_PTR` and back-propigate the change until the errors go away. If you come to a place where you can't, that part of the code needs to be redesigned.

Microsoft's own compiler now yields warnings for this stuff even in 32 bit compilation when the type isn't one of the pointer-in-integer types. Best to head the warnings.

Stuffing pointers in integers is not a recommended practice anymore, but the Win32 API does it all over the place, so when in Rome ...

Comment: I recommend you read the comment chain in my post, especially my most recent comment, and edit your answer accordingly so I may accept it.

Comment: @daedsidog: I have read it. I still recommend swapping the type for one of the pointer-in-integer types. The day may yet come when you need this code to run in 64 bit, and even if not, it's just plain old easier to read for the next guy.

Comment: I agree in spirit, but my hands are tied. Like you said; when in Rome...